DockerWare from shopware setup to show site
I am learning shopware, Figured out to run dockware with docker. Saw the admin page and localhost page. The issue is that localhost has the apache page and not the app page.

How can i learn more about shopware and dockerwave fast.
How do i set up the page to show on localhost?

I tried to add domains on the storeFront, allowed ip addresse too.
I want to see the front page of the app and not an Apache2 Default Page.
I used the docker compose example and dockerfile with the same result.
      ports:
         - "82:80"
         - "3306:3306"
         - "23:22"
         - "8888:8888"
         - "9998:9998"
         - "9999:9999"

EDIT:
docker run --rm -p 83:80 dockware/play:latest
I tried running docker directly with port 83, 80 is not available.
I can access the http://localhost:83/admin, but i can not find the running page.

Did you read all the documention to learn more? Also, how did you run the container?

docker-compose up. I can access admin page. Apache page is always there even if i am not running docker.
I saw https://docs.dockware.io/. Can not claim i read it all.
Maybe some port is taken for apache to show.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why not use the commands given in the documentation, like docker run --rm -p 80:80 dockware/play:latest?

image: dockware/dev:latest

"i can not find the running page" - what does that mean? Anything not working with http://localhost:83/. Also, if you haven't written any code on your own, please report this problem in their issue tracker

Thanks. I had to stop apache to make port 80 free. Then it worked (i was using 82 or 83)
